# lxml gcc failed with exit status 1 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, lxml

```
sudo easy_install lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.6.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/4f/3f/cf6daac551fc36cddafa1a71ed48ea5fd642e5feabd3a0d83b8c3dfd0cb4/lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz#md5=6dd7314233029d9dab0156e7b1c7830b
Processing lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-w86uerbh/lxml-3.6.4/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.6.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-w86uerbh/lxml-3.6.4/egg-dist-tmp-smgpuu2j
Building lxml version 3.6.4.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:83:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
/tmp/easy_install-w86uerbh/lxml-3.6.4/temp/xmlXPathInitmvs80t9r.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main (int argc, char **argv) {
 ^
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So how can i install lxml lib? I've tried pip, but there is the same finish.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

If this does not work, make sure that it is not a problem of memory, if so you will need to increase your machine memory.

Comment: The error ``fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`` is always indicative of ``python-dev`` package being missing. Lack of memory will not cause that error.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks, I got it. Just some times we get errors with `lxml` due to lack of memory.

Comment: My recollection is that I have seen memory issues with comping it too, but only when done inside of Docker builds where the build system was constraining the amount of memory you can use. The memory limit in that case was well below your typical desktop or laptop computer system.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add more memory to the instance in order to finish the lxml compilation